# How can I implement a centralized logging solution on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We need centralized logging in order to monitor, store, manage, and visualize logs for our infrastructure.

The logging solution must be able to capture messages from projects written in different languages such as Java, Angular, Scala, and Python.

Implementing a custom-built solution would lead to additional tasks, costs, and dependencies associated with managing and maintaining its components. So instead, we are thinking about using AWS Partner Network (APN) offerings.

What would be the best managed solution out of Splunk, Sumo Logic, Datadog, Elastic and Loggly?

Answer (score 0):

I have used many of solutions you mentioned. Splunk is good but it becomes really expensive if you have huge amount of data. You could have always used Cloudwatch Logs but it doesn't give you so much on visual part..

I will recommend ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana) stack. It is a very standard solution; in which logs are stored in Elastic Search. Kibana is used for visualization of logs. This works in almost real time.

If you have very specific dashboards; then you can always create custom dashboards using some front end technologies like AngularJS etc. but if visual part is really huge and very flexible then I feel ELK is better.

Answer (score 0):

ELK (ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana) stack is a really good solution for what you are looking for, but in some cases ELK is not going to be able to get some metrics, in this case you have some solutions like create your own **beat** program to get the information or use another program to gather this metrics like Apache NiFi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS CloudWatch, create a log stream for each of your application or service.
Define your custom metrics, create a dashboard and alert.

It's not limited to AWS things; you can use CloudWatch log agent for On-premises services or software on your local network.

For more information read the following article by Jeff Barr

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloudwatch-log-service/

and

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/improvements-to-cloudwatch-logs-dashboards/

FYI: we already monitor a lot of application and service inside and outside of AWS by CloudWatch, and it works like a charm.

Comment: CloudWatch only is not enough to monitor log messages across multiple log streams (you could still define filter metrics on the log streams and create dashboards using those, but you'd still have hard times monitoring log messages from multiple services). @SundarJavaDeveloper as others said the Logstash/ElasticSearch/Kibana solution is quite standard. Also check https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/centralized-logging/ for an AWS-suggested solution using ES and Kibana but providing the indexing via Kinesis + Lambda